# Can't preview PDF file on IE11/Windows

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a list of pdf files on a web application that a user can preview in a new tab when clicking on the name of the file.

It is working normally on all browsers but IE11, the only problem is that these pdf files have no .pdf file extension (this comes from the server and can't be changed) which seems to cause the problem.

Note the after opening the file in a new tab on IE11 I am seeing an empty gray screen but if I refresh the tab I can see the file normally.

Sample code:

```
   <h1>View Pdf Files</h1>
   <div>
       <a href="file_without_pdf_extension" target="_blank">View</a> // no preview
   </div>
   <div>
       <a href="file_with_pdf_extension" target="_blank">View</a> // preview
   </div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tested this issue on other computers using IE11? Does the same thing happen there? I wonder if its a rendering issue with the Adobe settings or a graphic acceleration issue. I believe PDF viewer has an `Enable hardware rendinger for legacy video cards` option for older hardware.

Comment: Please check your code, whether there has some JS code to based on the pdf file name to get the pdf file, then display it in the new tab?